# Word for arson by secret police

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Is there a word or phrase for when, during a protest meeting, the secret police lock the doors and set fire to the building?

Comment: There is nothing specific since this is rare in the English-speaking world, to rare to have a single-word for it.

Comment: I can't imagine this is common enough in any country to deserve its own word. And if there is such a country, I'm never visiting.

Comment: I suspect the word most usually used would be *murder,* possibly qualified as "state-sponsored murder".

Comment: @DanBron Yet _tear-gassing_ and _tas(er)ing_ are common enough that there are verbs for both actions (the former of which I would almost invariably associate with the police using tear gas against rioters/demonstrators, i.e., quite close to the meaning asked about here). It may be that there is no established term, but the act itself is certainly not unheard of, and it seems the kind of thing that is quite likely to develop a slang term to describe it, even if it doesn’t happen very often.

Comment: @Janus Tear-gassing and tasering were explicitly coined to describe a *new kind of device*. In the case of *tasering*, there was a deliberate and conscious decision made by two people to give a name to their invention (it's an acronym, after "*Thomas A. Swift's Electric Rifle*"); it didn't arise organically or in a grass-roots manner after the device was first applied. The specific act of the *secret police* *setting fire* to a *building they locked* in order to *quell a protest* is a different animal indeed. In other words, your words are *prescriptive*; OP's would need to be *descriptive*.

Comment: @DanBron The trademark may be deliberate, but the derived verb _tase_ certainly did arise organically, nearly 20 years after the advent of the Taser. Looking at this question in a slightly less narrow light, it’s not unheard of for police forces (secret or otherwise) to set fire to an occupied building to _smoke out_ the protesters. If there is a slang term (other than _smoke out_, which I personally wouldn’t use for actual fire) for that, then that would be an appropriate choice here. I doubt Tim is necessarily looking for something that must fit every single bit of the sentence exactly.

Comment: @Janus, yes, *tase* arose organically, but that's a *grammatical* innovation (and a rather mundane one), not a *semantic* innovation. The *semantic* innovation was the coining of the root *taser*, which is the device that causes injury. Analogously, the OP here is seeking a word which has the complex root meaning of "*the secret police setting fire ... quell a protest*", which I contend doesn't exist in English, broadly or narrowly. BTW, *smoke out* arose because it was common enough due to *hunting*, not police action. And at least where I'm from, it **is** uncommon, and would make headlines.

Comment: @DanBron I don’t disagree with anything you say, but that doesn’t mean there isn’t a slang phrase (probably taken over from something else, like _smoke out_) that refers to the police setting fire to a building to ‘fire out’ the people inside, just like there’s a word for the police firing tear gas into a crowd of people to disperse or repel them. Obviously, there won’t be a word that specifically refers to _secret_ police first _locking_ the doors of a building and _then_ setting fire to it, specifically while a _meeting_ about planning a _protest_ is going on inside. But close enough’ll do.

Comment: @Janus I believe the difference in the ultimate ends of "*smoke out*" vs "*fire out*" (dispersion vs mass murder) will put different linguistic pressures on the latter than the former, in that it may resist the euphemisation of being packaged into a single word (or maybe the opposite; after all, we have ["*muted kinetic actions*"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193149/the-meaning-of-muted-kinetics)). But overall I think that's a smaller influence than the fact that this action is as rare as it is extreme, and so there's been no need to describe it repeatedly, and therefore briefly.

Comment: If the secret policeman responsible is Archibald Fictitious De Shelby then the word is *antepastoilinessility*. But perhaps that scenario is more specific than the one you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

A similar event occurred in the French village of Oradour sur Glane on June 10, 1944, and during the prosecution of the perpetrators, their crime was referred to as a “massacre,”  an “atrocity,” and a “crime against humanity.”  The perpetrators referred to it as “collective punishment.”

Comment: Might be interesting to see how the French press or courts referred to it (in French); we might be able to borrow or coin an English term sharing the same roots.

Comment: @DanBron Taking your suggestion, I've waded through a few and the general term and cognate "massacre" seems to prevail. The bodies were all described as being "carbonisé," but "to carbonize" or "carbonization" would still not be specific enough.  Maybe "collective [punishment/retaliation by] carbonization/carbonizing."  Regardless, I'm just glad that, as you point out above, such an action seems to be too rare to need its own verb.